# error in running visallo using Maven

Tags: node.js, maven

i was trying to install and run visallo software for data analysis. i following documentation http://docs.visallo.org/getting-started.html
i cloned the source code successfully and when i run the command
 `mvn -DskipTests compile` command it is raising the error as

> ```
> Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.3:install-node-and-yarn (install-node-and-yarn) on project visallo-web: Could not extract the Yarn archive: Could not extract archive: '/home/sindhuja/.m2/repository/com/github/eirslett/yarn/0.17.10/yarn-0.17.10./yarn-v0.17.10.tar.gz': EOFException
> ```

the complete  error is

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.3:install-node-and-yarn (install-node-and-yarn) on project visallo-web: Could not extract the Yarn archive: Could not extract archive: '/home/sindhuja/.m2/repository/com/github/eirslett/yarn/0.17.10/yarn-0.17.10./yarn-v0.17.10.tar.gz': EOFException -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :visallo-web
```

[INFO] Visallo: Web: Base ................................. FAILURE [  1.077 s]
is where the error has raised

i installed all the required dependencies

1. nodejs version v4.7.2
2. git version 2.11.0
3. maven version 3.3.9
4. yarn version 0.24.5
5. ubuntu 17.04

pom.xml code is:
  https://github.com/visallo/visallo/blob/master/web/web-base/pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

It seems yarn may not have been downloaded correctly (similar issue: https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin/issues/450).

Try:

1. deleting `/home/sindhuja/.m2/repository/com/github/eirslett/`
2. re-run `mvn -DskipTests compile`